# Update app when an event is about to start, has started or has ended

Tags: android, service, google-cloud-firestore, android-workmanager

I'm new here so I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

I'm creating an app where I can upload themes (basically timed events) to a firestore db. The issue I'm having is how to properly manage these events. Currently I'm using the `WorkManager` to schedule reading from the database every hour to check if any new themes have been added, the problem with this however is that the service may not have been started yet so when the app is opened the empty state I created is displayed and I couldn't figure out a way to manually start the service via swipe to refresh or something similar.

It's also currently set to sync my offline room db with the new themes once it actually fetches them from firestore, which works quite well. However I want to make it more fluid and more automated, which is why I opted to go with the `WorkManager`

If it's worth noting, I tried using `SharedPreferences` to keep track of the status of the theme and send a notification based on that status (whether it's starting, has started or ended) but the issue with this is that I had to clear App Data every time I installed the app to make it work.

How exactly would you go about doing this?

A nudge in the right direction is prefered but a code example is also welcome (maybe pseudo code).

**Worker Class:**

```
@Override
@NonNull
public Result doWork() {
        try{

            Query query = firestore.collection("themes").orderBy("start_time");

            query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot : task.getResult()){
                            if(snapshot.exists()){
                                Themes themes = snapshot.toObject(Themes.class);

                                themeKey = snapshot.getId();

                                DateTime today = new DateTime();
                                DateTime start_time = new DateTime(themes.start_time);
                                DateTime end_time = start_time.plus(INTERVAL);

                                if (today.isBefore(start_time)) {
                                    CurrentTheme currentTheme = new CurrentTheme(themes.theme_name, themes.theme_description,
                                            String.valueOf(start_time.getMillis()), "Starts in: ", themeKey, themes.sponsor_url, themes.theme_img);

                                    mFirebaseMethods.insert(currentTheme);

                                    if(!FireApp.getPreferences().getBoolean("starting", false)){
                                        notifyThemeStatus(currentTheme.getTheme_name() + " starting at " +
                                                start_time.toString(), FireApp.getApp()
                                                .getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0).getString("regId", null));

                                        editor = FireApp.getPreferences().edit();
                                        editor.putBoolean("starting", true);
                                        editor.putBoolean("started", false);
                                        editor.putBoolean("ended", false);
                                        editor.apply();
                                    }

                                } else if(today.isAfter(start_time) && today.isBefore(end_time)){
                                    mFirebaseMethods.deleteByTime(String.valueOf(start_time.getMillis())); 

                                    CurrentTheme currentTheme = new CurrentTheme(themes.theme_name, themes.theme_description,
                                            String.valueOf(end_time.getMillis()), "Ends in: ", themeKey, themes.sponsor_url, themes.theme_img);

                                    mFirebaseMethods.update(currentTheme);

                                    if(!FireApp.getPreferences().getBoolean("started", false)) {
                                        notifyThemeStatus(themes.theme_name + " ends " +
                                                getRelativeTimeSpanString(themes.start_time + INTERVAL).toString(), FireApp.getApp()
                                                .getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0).getString("regId", null));

                                        editor = FireApp.getPreferences().edit();
                                        editor.putBoolean("starting", false);
                                        editor.putBoolean("started", true);
                                        editor.apply();
                                    }
                                } else if (today.isAfter(end_time)){

                                    CurrentTheme currentTheme = new CurrentTheme(themes.theme_name, themes.theme_description,
                                            String.valueOf(0), "Ended", themeKey, themes.sponsor_url, themes.theme_img);

                                    mFirebaseMethods.update(currentTheme);

                                    //checkWinner(themeKey, themes.start_time, themes.theme_name);

                                    if(!FireApp.getPreferences().getBoolean("ended", false)) {

                                        notifyThemeStatus(themes.theme_name + " has ended.", FireApp.getApp()
                                                .getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF, 0).getString("regId", null));

                                        editor = FireApp.getPreferences().edit();
                                        editor.putBoolean("ended", true);
                                        editor.putBoolean("started", false);
                                        editor.apply();
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            return Result.SUCCESS;
        }catch (Throwable throwable){
            Log.e("PopulateThemeCache", "Error caching", throwable);
            return Result.FAILURE;
        }
    }
```

Where I start the worker in my application class:

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();

PeriodicWorkRequest populateCache = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(PopulateThemeCache.class, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .addTag("Theme_Update")
            .build();

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(populateCache);
```

`mFirebaseMethods` is a repository class which has all the asynctask code to perform room db operations

Comment: Add your attempt to your question so we can better help you solve your problem.

Comment: @GrantMiller done, let me know if there is anything else I should add. Most of the necessary code is in the worker class though.